# NameError: uninitialized constant Sass::SCSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting NameError: uninitialized constant Sass::SCSS 
while doing rake db:migrate

below is my gemfile

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
group :development, :test, :qa do
  #gem 'rcov', '=0.9.11'
  #gem 'brakeman'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'simplecov-rcov'
end
gem 'sitemap_generator', '= 4.3.1'


gem 'quickbase_client', '~> 1.0.24'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sqlite3'
#gem for rspec to evaluate cookies
gem "show_me_the_cookies"
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

# For GEOIP LBS API use, this gem is needed for harmony_cms gem 1.24.04
gem 'timezone', ">= 0.3.2"

# Gems added for the Paryoll App
gem 'therubyracer', ">= 0.11.4", :platform => :ruby
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem "capybara"
gem "js-test-driver-rails", "~> 0.4.3.2"
gem 'useragent'
gem 'nokogiri', "=1.6.5"

# TODO: this belongs in Showroom_Plugin, but for now I'm adding it here to unbreak QA environment
#gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'


gem 'debugger', :group => [:development, :test]
```

Comment: Well I guess because the `sass-rails` gem is in the `:assets` group...

Comment: I moved it to below assets group but got same error

Answer (score 2):

Remove `gem 'sass-rails'` form `assets` group

```
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
group :assets do
  #remove from here. gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
end
```